# How to configure an iPhone to download complete email everytime

Tags: pop3, iphone

We have a user with an iPhone 4s who receives email via POP.
His email has been working normally until recently when he reported that the body of some messages do not download. In place of the body the iPhone displays, "This message has not been downloaded from the server."
These are routine messages. Some (but not all) have attachments. Some are from senders who are normally received without a problem.

Does anyone know how to configure an iPhone to download the complete message everytime?

Also; Does anyone know how the iPhone mail app receives mail?
Does it, for example, download headers first and retrieve bodys later?

Answer (score 2):

I have a limited knowledge apart from being an iPhone owner, however I know this can happen with old archived emails, and also with emails which have attachments over 1MB total in size. It could also happen if the email is in an unsupported format such as RTF. See: http://support.apple.com/kb/TS1506

Lastly, it could also happen if the mail folders are out of sync, for example if a user is trying to access a Gmail message that was loaded to the phone and later deleted from the mail server via the Gmail.com site directly.
https://discussions.apple.com/message/7874719#7874719